# How can i read all application logs from AWS cloudwatch using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using AWS lambda functions with spring boot and i able to see my all logs in AWS cloudwatch.

But now I want to get all those logs generated by my application.

Because I want to send those log files via mail.

Comment: where do you host your application? on which server it is running?

Comment: Its on AWS lambda, 
spring-boot serverless application

Comment: then it should log application logs it self

Comment: No its not writing, AWS lambda has read-only memory.
they has /tmp where you write your data temporary, I tried this approach as well. But its not creating file there.

i can see all my application-logs on cloudwatch but unable to fetch it

Comment: You can use awscli/AWS SDK to fetch the logs from CloudWatch logs.